# SplashScreen no funciona. Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

Tengo una app funcionando y ahora le quise agregar motionLayout a mi splash screen para que tenga una aminación bonita pero, por algún motivo, dejó de funcionar. Ahora, cuando le doy click a run, en el virtual device me aparece por un par de segundos una pantalla blanca y luego la activity que le debería seguir al splash, saltandose por completo la primera activity.
Intenté deshacer todo volviendo al constraint layout para que vuelva a funcionar pero no lo hace. Le borré incluso el xml asociado al splash y creé otro (solo debería mostrar una imagen ahora) pero aun así no funciona.
Le agregué unos breakpoint al splash para ver si tenía algún error pero no para en ninguno, como que no ejecuta esa activity para nada.

Esta es mi SplashScreen (JAVA)

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent("independent.dev.ui.mainactivity");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

el código del layout del splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@color/green">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

en el  build.gradle tengo esto implementado
`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'`

en el manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Ayuda porfavor!!! no sé qué hacer para que ejecute esta activity

Comment: Hola, y que error te da ? puedes añadirlo al codigo, eso ayudara, gracias.

Comment: Hola @amj2020, ninguno, ese es el problema. Simplemente no carga desde el splash si no que desde otra activity. Creo que no tiene nada que ver con el layout si no que me estoy perdiendo algún otro detalle

Comment: no se te entiende, pero si es sobre la pantalla blanca que sale al cargar al iniciar eso es asi por que android esta haciendo espacio en memoria para tu app y pausa la carga del activity.  Para sacar esa pantalla blanca ponle un tema personalizado atu activity splash , este tema style tiene que tener windowsbackground un drawable ese drawable pon tu logo. Ya que al pausar la carga lo que se muestra es el windows background que es una pantalla blanca.